# Minimum tiling of a rectangle by squares

Tags: tiling, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, algorithms, linear-programming

Given the $n\times m$ rectangle, I want to compute the minimum number of integer-sided squares needed to tile it (possibly of different sizes).
Is there an efficient way to calculate this?

Comment: Euclidean algorithm gives an upper bound quickly: for m < n, something like O(n/m + log m + m/gcd(n,m)).  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.11.02

Comment: I can give an even quicker upper bound..$mn$. I guess a $5 \times 6$ rectangle shows that the greedy/Euclidean strategy does not always give the minimum.

Comment: Nice example, Aaron.  Perhaps a dynamic programming approach would improve upon a greedy one?   At least the greedy algorithm might help tune a branch-and-bound algorithm.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.11.02 

Comment: Tiling a rectangle with the fewest squares. Kenyon, Richard J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 76 (1996), no. 2, 272–291.

http://www.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcta.1996.0104 

"We show that a square-tiling of a p×q rectangle, where p and q are relatively prime integers, has at least log 2p squares. If q>p we construct a square-tiling with less than q/p+Clogp squares of integer size, for some universal constant C.''



Comment: Also see. Rectangles as sums of squares. Walters, Mark 
Discrete Math. 309 (2009), no. 9, 2913–2921.http://www.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2008.07.028  Where precisely this question is discussed and is ascribed to Laczkovich (i.e., the minimum number of squares needed to tile an integer sided rectangle ( the squares are not assumed to be integer sided though)). Of course you are asking for an efficient algorithm which is a different question ... Kenyon paper does discuss some algorithm(greedy) though.  

Comment: See also the question http://mathoverflow.net/q/116382/7252 which refers to this one.