# tiling a rectangle with squares: how unique are the minimal solutions?

Tags: tiling, co.combinatorics

This is a follow-up of [my recent thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116382/tiling-a-rectangle-with-the-smallest-number-of-squares) about tiling a $m\times n$ rectangle with squares:

I'm wondering to what extent a minimal tiling is *essentially unique*, that is, up to reflections of the whole rectangle or of (tiled) rectangles contained in it. I guess this definition is tantamount to saying that the collection of the square sides is unique.

First, let me suggest a more suitable definition of reducibility than in the other thread:

> We'll call a rectangle (or a minimal tiling of it) *reducible* if it can be split into two (tiled) rectangles.

By playing around a bit with irreducible tilings, I have the impression that there are always some of the squares that form a smaller rectangle, but that apart from reflections inside of those smaller rectangle(s), such a tiling is unique.

> Are all irreducible tilings essentially unique?
>
> Do all minimal tilings contain a (tiled) rectangle?

The smallest irreducible rectangles are

$(13,11)\quad  (17,16)\quad  (19,16)\quad  (19,17)\quad  (19,18)\quad  (20,17)\quad  (21,19)\quad  (25,23)\quad $ $  (26,22)\quad (27,23)\quad  (27,25)\quad  (28,27)\quad  (29,25)\quad  (29,27)\quad  (31,23)\quad  (31,25)\quad $ $ (31,26)\quad  (31,27)\quad  (31,28)\quad  (31,29)\quad  (31,30)\quad  (32,27)\quad  (32,29)\quad  (32,31)\quad  $ $ (33,26)\quad  (33,28)\quad  (34,25)\quad  (34,32)\quad  (35,31)\quad  (35,34)\quad (36,31)\quad  (37,29) $.

**Now looking at *reducible rectangles*:**

Note that a reducible rectangle can be splittable horizontally or vertically, often in several ways, and sometimes both at a time. For example, $f(15,8)=f(7,8)+f(8,8)=f(15,3)+f(15,5)$. So those tilings are far from unique. But now:

> We'll call a rectangle (or a minimal tiling of it) *coprime-reducible* if the rectangle can be split into two (tiled) rectangles that have coprime sides each.

For a given $m\le 85$, the majority (in average about 90%) of the $m\times n $ rectangles with $n\lt m$ are reducible. But in the whole range, there is **no** rectangle that is coprime-reducible...

> Is it possible to show that coprime-reducible rectangles don't exist?

EDIT: Note that as the values $f(m,n)$ for given m and for coprime $n$ between $m/2$ and $2m$ are seemingly very close to each other, the value of a coprime-reducible one in this range would have to be about the double of the others. This sort of rules out their existence heuristically.

Comment: I think it is feasible to do a near-brute force search on minimal square tilings for rectangles of small dimensions.  Knowing that a tiling of O(log(pq)) exists for a p by q rectangle means a branch and bound algorithm can scan the possibilities pretty quickly to find all minimal tilings.  Using theory to make good choices for p and q should allow a nice exploration, perhaps even for p into the thousands.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.12.17

Answer (score 2):

I just found that the answer to the first question about uniqueness is **negative**.

> We have $f(34,29)=9$, and there are at least two essential different minimal tilings:
>
> - an irreducible one (squares of sides 19,15,14,10,10 clockwise and 4x1 in the middle)
> - a reducible one (squares of sides 17,17,12,12,6,4,4,4 clockwise and another one of side 6 in the middle)